# Sort Realm by (Alphabet, Number, Special Characters)

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm new to realm. I created a songbook app and I need to display the songs alphabetically. from A to Z to numbers and special characters. My sort looks like this.

```
realm.objects(T.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "title")
```

It is sorting my list but the problem is special characters are always in the top of the list. Now I want to achieve sorting it by Alphabet first then numbers and lastly special characters. Can anyone help me on this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you need to keep the sorted collection as an auto-updating `Results` instance or is it fine if its converted to an `Array` in order to achieve the sorting?

Comment: fine to be converted into an array. But it contains thousands of records.

Comment: @AlvinJohn, find my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
   let objects = realm.objects(T.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "title", ascending: true)
```

Or sort it after you get your array using

```
let sortedObjects = objects.sorted { $0.title.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.title) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending }
```

Comment: @a-munzer - it seems that these two methods do not return the same results. The result of the sort descriptor you provided for the `realm.objects.sortedByKeyPath` will be: `[As, Cool, Ąć, Ćma]`. The result for the `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` will be valid: `[As, Ąć, Cool, Ćma]`. I gave you +1 for providing two sort methods, however youre response needs to be updated.